Is it possible to arrange two or more lenses and mirrors so that I can focus both sun’s rays at a single point
I know similar questions have been asked but I’m still not convinced. I understand it would violate 2nd law of thermodynamics to generate a temperature hotter than the sun using one lens. I’m asking if two or more lens/mirror arrangement can produce temperature hotter than sun.

If it was only a matter of the number of lenses used to beat it, it wouldn't be called a Law, would it? No, it doesn't matter how many optical elements you use, it is not possible to create a higher temperature than the source. Per 2nd Law.

Please add references to the questions. It will help us to post a satisfying answer.

I feel this is a good starting point, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/143049/what-temperature-is-achieved-in-focus-point-by-5000-flat-1x1cm-mirrors-onto-a-sa In addition, I believe that it would be helpful to specify the "material". E.g. I believe that higher temperatures are achievable in plasma physics, but the plasma is isolated.
